# Calculate Desirability index using SciPy statistical distributions

Tags: python, statistics, scipy

I am trying to calculate the [desirability index](http://www.lorentzcenter.nl/lc/web/2009/359/presentations/Trautmann.pdf) (DI) from a range of descriptors, in this case distributions of specific properties. The DI requires values to be scaled [0 .. 1], where 0 is undesirable and 1 accordingly the most desirable. In terms of my distributions, a variate with the highest probability should then have a value of 1, the lowest probability (close to) 0.

My question is now how can I apply this to the distributions I have fitted with SciPy? For example, given a normal distribution, `scipy.stats.norm(loc=0.0, scale=1.0)`, `scipy.stats.norm.pdf(0, loc=0.0, scale=1.0)` would be most desirable variate with the largest probability (`0.4`). How can I scale the probabilities from 0 to 1, for other types of distributions in particular?

Comment: Shouldn't `scipy.stats.norm.pdf(0, loc=0.0, scale=1.0)` be the least desirable variable and `scipy.stats.norm.pdf(1, loc=0.0, scale=1.0)` be the most desirable variable base on your description?

Comment: I found now what I need, namely the mode of the distribution if it is analytically available.